Hypothesis Testing Between Two Sets of Time Series
I want to verify the reproducibility of a capture method by comparing two sets of time series captured at different times.
Let's consider two sets of time series $A=(tsa_1,\dots,tsa_n)$ and $B=(tsb_1,\dots,tsb_m)$ with $n,m >> 100$.
Let's also define $H_0$=The two datasets are consistent with each other, and $H_a$=The two datasets show significant variations.
What would be the classic way to test these hypotheses?
I came up with distance-based methods, but I would like to explore statistical methods to compare. I read about statistical tests but I could not find much information on dealing with time series. Any help or direction to resources is appreciated.
For the sake of the argument, we can consider data similar to the plot below. These are synthetic data generate with normal noise around pre-defined patterns but the real captured data are expected to have the same properties.


What do the time series data look like? You are asking for methods without giving sufficient context.

Looks like patch clamp recordings of single ion channels. I would look at that literature for methods as it is (was?) full of very clever scientists.

Does look similar but my experiment is nowhere near this topic. I am looking for general and robust methods that do not take the specific shape of the patterns into account.

The most basic statistical approaches might focus on the mean values, and it seems to me that those might be totally irrelevant to your inferential purposes. Therefore you need first to decide what aspects of the data you would consider 'consistent' and what 'reproducible' would look like. For some purposes the fact that the red and blue signals have sharp transitions and two plateau levels is similar. For other contexts it is the time between transitions that might be more important, or the plateau levels themselves.
Once you have some idea of what to look for then you want to pull those values out of the data. If the signals were ion channel currents from patch clamp experiments it would be sensible to define first the transitions between conduction states, and then pull out the average current values at each plateau, or the spectrum of durations of the conduction states and the like. Just saying that the data are like those in the picture does is not specific enough for specific advice.
